# How to delete a file using cloud function JavaScript firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to delete the file from storage when a data node is deleted from the realtime database. the name of the file to be deleted is taken before deleted. The name of the file is saved in the node in child named "imageTitle". The code works fine before implementing the file delete code. I mean the nodes get deleted perfectly.

When I implement the file delete code the rest doesn't work, but there is no any errors. The code after file delete doesn't work. I dunno why.

This is for an academic final project.

There's a folder named images in the bucket, and the file I need to delete is in there. The file name is taken from the child in the node which is to be deleted in the realtime database named imageTitle:

```
    'use strict';

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();


    exports.changetime = functions.database.ref('/posts/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const editDate = Date.now()
    datas = snapshot.val();
    return snapshot.ref.update({editDate})
})

    const CUT_OFF_TIME = 1 * 60 * 1000; 

/**
 * This database triggered function will check for child nodes that are older than the
 * cut-off time. Each child needs to have a `timestamp` attribute.
 */


    exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/posts/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change, 
    context) => {
    const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    const now = Date.now();
    const id = context.params.pushId;
    const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
    const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('createdDate').endAt(cutoff);
    const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');

    const getImageTitle = admin.database().ref(`/posts/${id}/imageTitle`).once('value');

    return getImageTitle.then(imageTitle => {

    console.log('post author id', imageTitle.val());
    const imageName =  imageTitle.val();
    const filePath = 'images/' + imageName;


    const path = `images/${imageName}`;
    const bucket = app.storage().bucket();
    return bucket.file(path).delete().then(() =>{
    console.log(`File deleted successfully in path: ${imageName}`)

/* The problem is here. the code doesn't work after file.delete function. no errors. but doesn't work
if I remove that piece of code the other codes work fine. I mean the realtime database nodes get deleted and updated perfectly */

    const updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
    if(updates[child.key] == null){
    admin.database().ref(/post-likes/+id).remove();
   }
   })

   return ref.update(updates);
   });
   });
   [my storage looks like this][1]});
```

There's a folder named images in the bucket, and the file I need to delete is in there. The file name is taken from the child in the node which id to be deleted in the realtime database imageTitle:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xou7J.png)

Comment: You seem to be missing quotes around the path in the reference in this code: ```admin.database().ref(/post-likes/+id).remove()``` Not sure if that is you only issue. Doing this on my phone.

Comment: that part of the code is working fine. the problem is with the file deleteion. i just dunno how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```
const filePath = 'images/' + imageName;


const path = `images/${imageName}`;
```

You should be using `filePath` not `path` in your bucket reference. `` const path = `images/${imageName}`; `` is wild-card syntax used when querying, not when assigning variables....think you stayed in 'Dart' mode here:-). Not sure what `path` contains, therefore, but console.log it to see.

Here is some code that I use to delete images from my storage bucket that works perfectly. First, a couple of things to check (best done using console.log, never assume you know what is in the variable), and do:

1. Ensure `imageName`, `filePath`, `path` and `bucket` contain what they should contain.
2. Include the `.catch` block in your code to check if there actually is an error
3. I am not clear if `` console.log(`File deleted successfully in path: ${imageName}`) `` is executing but if it isn't then your file.delete must be throwing an error which the catch block should trap.

The code snippet:

```
const oldProfileImagePath = "profileImages/" + authenticatedUserId + "/" + oldProfileImageName;
      return bucket.file(oldProfileImagePath).delete()
        .then(function () {
          console.info("Old Profile Image: " + oldProfileImagePath + " deleted!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Remove Old Profile Image: " + oldProfileImagePath +
            " failed with " + error.message)
        });
```

Comment: thanks @GrahamD . thnx for helping me fixing this issue. what you mentioned was also the problem. and there was another problem with returning the promisses.

Comment: `const updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    updates[child.key] = null;
    admin.database().ref(/post-likes/+id).remove();
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(ref.update(updates));
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    promises.push(bucket.file(filePath).delete());
  })
  

  // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
  return Promise.all(promises);`

Comment: Your welcome. Glad I could help. Hadn't spotted the return issue. Please upvote the answer as well if you would, gives me a few more reputation points and keeps me motivated. Thanks. :-)